# Can authentication cookie be shared between two .Net Core 2.0 applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-2.0

I have been trying to set up two (and eventually more) .NET Core 2.0 API's.

One that would handle authentication, creating the claims and storing them in a cookie. Ideally the other(s) should then use this same cookie to grant access to authorized endpoints.

I have however encountered some issues, with the second service not identifying - or using - the cookie I've created in the auth service.

My Startup.cs file (for both services) looks like this...

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
                {
                    Name = ".AuthCookie",
                    Domain = "localhost",
                    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                    HttpOnly = false
                };

                // Events
                // On redirect to login, return 401
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                // On access denied, return 403
                options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

For testing purposes I created an HttpGet call for creating the claims, and so that endpoint looks like this...

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task Login()
    {
        // Generate the list of claims
        // TODO: Generate claims based on data from post
        var claims = new List
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "identifier"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "name")
        };

        // Create the claims identity
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");

        // Initialize the principal
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        // Sign in using the principal
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

        // Return the all-clear
        return Ok("Logged in");
    }
```

So over all, the service that creates this cookie can use it, but other services struggle to see that the you should be authenticated.

Both services are run in docker containers, if that is of relevance, and are accessed through the localhost domain, as such: `http://localhost:{ServicePort}`

I'm at my wits end, as I have been unable to find any helpful documentation, and most articles on cookie sharing seem to predate the current implementation in .NET Core 2.0

Any hints on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

### Solution

As provided by [Evk](/users/5311735/evk), I had to enable the service [AddDataProtection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x) and persists they keys on a file system that both (or all) services can access.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"/appdata"));
```

Comment: Which are the domain names you use to access those applications? Are they same\share top level domain? Because if they are completely different domains - browser won't send cookie from one to another.

Comment: Both are running on localhost, with different ports assigned. http://localhost:32769 for auth service, http://localhost:32770 for the one trying to read the cookie.

Comment: Just to be sure, you access them in browser like "http :// localhost:32769"?

Comment: Correct, in both cases I access them as `http://localhost:{ServicePort}`, I have edited the question to mention this. :)

Comment: In this case cookie should be shared between two applicaitons. Then problem might be in configuration of data protection provider. You can try read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x. And configure both of your applications to use data protection provider to store keys in one folder. Those keys are used to encrypt\decrypt data in a cookie, and if two applications use different keys - they cannot decrypt each other data.

Comment: @Evk could you please add this to an answer so I can tag it as the right one. I had to create a shared volume in docker and have the key dropped in there. I also had to change the domain from `.localhost` to just `localhost`.